# D-Link DWA-130 rev E1 RTL8191SU hard time connecting

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

I have a D-Link DWA-130 rev E1 with a RTL8191SU chip set. Under Ubuntu 14.04 it will connect to the router occasionally, most of the time it tries and fails over and over. It seems to connect with out issue on one of my machines that is running 12.04. Any help would be appreciated.

### lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2805 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 07d1:3300 D-Link System DWA-130 802.11n Wireless N Adapter(rev.E) [Realtek RTL8191SU]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Is it a usb dongle? Then please [edit] your post and add there output of "lsusb" terminal command.

Comment: I am still have a problem with the dongle.   I can connect to a g router OK and it works fine.  When I connect to an N router, it stays connected but throughput stops for a time and then it starts again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a good driver by running

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Then reboot.

You will need to install it after each kernel update. You can keep `rtlwifi_new` folder and just run last 3 commands.

In case you have no other way to get internet connection, you can download this driver in Windows or using another computer. Do it this way:

1. Download the driver [AS A ZIP ARCHIVE](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/archive/master.zip).
2. Extract it to your home directory. You will get `rtlwifi_new-master` folder there.
3. Run in terminal:

   ```
   cd rtlwifi_new-master
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

Comment: Pilot6, your solution worked.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I made this driver as a [DKMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) module and added it to ppa.

If the driver is installed from ppa, it will rebuild after each kernel upgrade. Install it this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

For Ubuntu 14.04 users, if there are still issues I recommend to install new `linux-firmware` backported from 15.04. It contains new firmware for various devices, including Realtek wireless.

It can be installed from same repository by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```