# D-Link DWA-130 rev E1 RTL8191SU Wont Connect to Network (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, realtek, realtek-wireless

Having a problem with getting my  D-Link usb Wi-Fi dongle to connect to my wifi network.

The dongle works, it scans and gives back the SSID's that are available, however when I try to connect, it will not, it attempts connection and fails, then retries. Every once in a while it will work, but it seems completely random.

[I tried this fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627393/d-link-dwa-130-rev-e1-rtl8191su-hard-time-connecting) and my wifi connected, when I restarted, after a bit I shut the system down, came back the next day and my wifi dongle is back to the connection loop from hell

Comment: Did you try to re-install the driver again? If you install kernel updates, you need to re-install the driver.

Comment: yea i did it twice, after following ur instructions i restart like you say, when the system reboots my net works... i can sit there and click the disconnect button, then reconnect. and it works fine, as soon as i restart my system again it stops working.... no this is random when it decides to work and when it does not, so i can not say for sure that  your previous fix has had any effect or im just hitting a time when its feeling like working

Comment: when the unbuntu system is shut down i use the same wifi dongle in a windows pc and have absolutely no problems, i also have two cellphones that connect to the network so i know that's not the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by re-installing the driver and running

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

after that.

Comment: alright, thanks for your time and help. I will give this a shot now and let ya know how it goes

Comment: First try then thank.)) And if it works, then accept the answer by clickin the "bird" at the left.

Comment: might seem stupid but should i have dongle connected durring this or disconnected or does it matter ?

Comment: It does not matter, I think.

Comment: Ok... knock on wood.... your solution works, or seems to for now. i have disconnected and reconnected, restarted and shutdown, with and without dongle connected. It connects or reconnects within 5 seconds of powering on or plugging in.

Comment: You mentioned that i would have to re apply this if i do a kernel update, I am rather new to Linux. will the kernel update automatically or just through the software update application or terminal command ?

Comment: When you install routine suggested updates look if there are linux-image packages. If there are, then you will need to install the driver again after updates and reboot. Unless you install the driver using dkms. I hopa I get myself to make a dkms package.

Comment: @Anthony I made a dkms module. You can find it at http://askubuntu.com/questions/627393/d-link-dwa-130-rev-e1-rtl8191su-hard-time-connecting