# Speed problem with my new D-Link (DWA-130) USB Adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, d-link

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, however I have taken some effort to follow some of the solutions from others on here with similar versions of my hardware, to no avail.
Some of the solutions I've tried.

1. [Install DWA-131 WiFi dongle driver under Ubuntu 14.04.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738911/install-dwa-131-wifi-dongle-driver-under-ubuntu-14-04-4/738997#738997)
2. [D-Link DWA-130 rev E1 RTL8191SU Wont Connect to Network (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627995/d-link-dwa-130-rev-e1-rtl8191su-wont-connect-to-network-14-04)

I'm getting desperate at this point. What am I missing? Please help!

I have a Windows 10 dual boot which runs the same USB adaptor at a much higher speed so I know the issue is not with the WiFi signal. (70+ Mbps vs 2-3 Mbps in Ubuntu)

My current Ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS and  I get  `4.13.0-32-generic`. From `uname -r`

The result from `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0461:4e6f Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:008a Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2001:3c25 D-Link Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My result from `lsmod | grep ^rt` is:

```
rt2800usb              28672  0
rt2x00usb              20480  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib             110592  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              53248  3 rt2800lib,rt2800usb,rt2x00usb
```

My result from `sudo lshw -class network`

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 10
       serial: b0:35:9f:76:20:f5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-32-generic firmware=29.610311.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:41 memory:fe900000-fe901fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 11
       serial: 98:ee:cb:62:06:d1
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:35 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe800000-fe800fff memory:d0800000-d0803fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@3:1
       logical name: wlx74dada32f98d
       serial: 74:da:da:32:f9:8d
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.13.0-32-generic firmware=0.29 ip=192.168.0.26 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

[patebin containing my wireless info.](https://pastebin.com/j1YyyHR3)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would much rather tweak the much higher quality internal Intel device!

Comment: thanks  @chili555 I'll give that a shot, I assumed being in a basement setup that a USB connected dongle would give me better results.

Comment: I suggest that you detach the USB and try the internal. If you need help after that, start a new question and I’ll be happy to help.

Comment: @chili555, as per your advice I have started a new question, thanks so much for your help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005988/very-slow-wifi-speeds-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-4-13-0-32-generic-with-intel-iwlwifi